# How to implement sample_ and sbm() functions in the newer versions of igraph in R?

Tags: r, igraph

I have a line of code that used to work perfectly:

```
sbm_2 <- sample_(sbm(n = 200,pref.matrix = diag(0.2, 2) + 0.2, block.sizes = c(100, 100)),vertex_attr("true_block" ,rep(1:2, each = 100)) )
```

However, ever since igraph updated itself, this coding hasn't been working anymore and I am really not sure how to reconstruct it according to the new rules. The `sbm` function above is a stochastic block model with a `sample_` function on the outside. Does anyone have any ideas how to convert the above so that it works in `igraph` again?

Comment: This seems to have been replaced with `sample_sbm`.  I do not see how to pass in your vertex attribute, but this works for me. `sbm_2 <- sample_sbm(n = 200,pref.matrix = diag(0.2, 2) + 0.2, 
 block.sizes = c(100, 100))`

Comment: I am hoping to pass the true block argument as it seems to randomize over it. Are there other solutions?